# ajax post doesn't give any indication

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
$("#submitbutton").button().click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tst/mmm.php',
        data: { abc: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" },
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});

# cat tst/mmm.php
<?php echo json_encode(array("first"=>"YyXy","last"=>"yyyyXXX")); ?>
```

Why cant i see an alert that tells me *first=YyXy&last=yyyyXXX* . if it means anything, there is access to mmm.php from remote. They are both on apache. Where should i look for the response of this post? Sorry for the lame questions in the subject,i'm new to it. Thanx!!

EDIT 1: html code:

```
 <body>
            <div id=container>
            <div id="first">
                    <form id='form1'>
                            <button id="submitbutton" type="submit">Submit</button></br></br>
                    </form>
            </div>
```

EDIT 2 :
Do I need special user:group permissions for the html to post to php?
Should I use some special settings to allow access to mmm.php in apache configuration (httpd.conf) ?

Comment: is js code provided wrapped in `$(document).ready(...)` ?

Comment: Did you try this? `$("#submitbutton").button().click(`

Comment: its a typo. not exists in code. sry about that guys :)

Comment: See updated answer. I think your success listener is in the wrong place.

Comment: @Li3ro you should use developer tools to avoid problems like this....

Comment: you are right! i use vim and its not good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) they state the following:

> **Deprecation Notice:** The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks
>       will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use
>       jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

so i used their example and now it looks like that(and works) :

```
$("#submitbutton").button().click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mmm.php',
        data: { abc: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" } })
        .done(function() { alert("success"); })
        .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
        .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
   });
});
```

thank you guys!!

Comment: Interesting. I'm using jquery 1.7.2. I will change this events too.

Comment: LoL.. now i'm getting 304 from the apache. it never ends

Answer (score 7):

Possible reasons this does not work:

- Are you sure your selector goes like `$("submitbutton")`? this tells jQuery to look for tag `submitbutton`. Perhaps, you meant `$("#submitbutton")` or `$('.submitbutton')`.
- Is your js code wrapped in `$(document).ready(...)` ? Unless jQuery may not know about whole DOM tree.

Comment: +1, great minds think alike. Selector looks like the culprit.

Comment: (1) selector issue is a typo. sry   (2) it does wrapped in $(document).ready(...)

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your full HTML code it's hard to know for sure, but your selector looks wrong. If "submitbutton" is an id attribute then your selector should be:

```
$("#submitbutton")
```

and if it is a class it should be:

```
$(".submitbutton")
```

EDIT:

Shouldn't your AJAX code have the success function inside the ajax settings? Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'tst/mmm.php',
    data: { abc: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: it is inside ajax block, the whitespace format is misleading. will edit the above code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({   
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'tst/mmm.php',
       data: { abc: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" }
        })
       .success(function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
        })
```

Comment: I found the answer! you are in the right direction, only .success is deprecated from 1.8 and on.. thanx for the hint for solution!!!!